# Search inside extjs tree store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a textfield in my tree toolbar that should take a string from a user then search that through a specific column of tree. I use store filter but there is a problem in my code and I dont know what it is. thanks for help.
This is my code:

```
var onSimpleSearch = function(){
 var searchStr= Ext.getCmp('searchField').getValue();
   if(searchStr){
    var tree = Ext.getCmp('infra_tree');
    var tstore = tree.getStore();
    var searchReg = new RegExp(".*" + searchStr + ".*", "ig");
    console.log(searchReg); //return RegExp!!!!!!!
    tstore.filter("ipadd", searchReg});
}else {
    Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title: 'Nothing to search',
        msg: 'Search string is empty',
        icon : 'ext-mb-info',
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: debug it. if you replace searchReg in the filter() call with a hard coded value, does it work?

Comment: I did, It doesnt, I think there is no implementing for tree store filter, it is fake! what should i do now? how to filter my data in store? :(

Comment: This thread shows some more background, but not yet a working implementation: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?43909-Search-Operation-in-tree-control

Answer (score 3):

There is no `filter` method in `Ext.data.TreeStore` (assuming you are using 4.x, I am using 4.1.3).
Maybe this will help you:
[Ext JS 4: Filtering a TreeStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627821/ext-js-4-filtering-a-treestore)

Alternatively, you could try something like this:

```
var nodeToSearchFor = treestore.getRootNode().findChildBy(function(node) {
    return (node.data['fieldToSearchFor'] == valueToSearchFor);
});
```

And hopefully one last edit :-)
In this thread in the Sencha forums, they are suggesting you use `CascadeBy` on the root node. Works same way as the code above more or less.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?150060-Search-inside-extjs-tree-store

Answer (score 0):

You could walk over all child nodes in the tree instead of going through the store. All nodes of the tree implement the [TreeNodeInterface](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface) which has the methods you need. The `cascadeBy` method is probably what you are looking for. It will call a function recursively on each child node of a node. That is essentially the same as a filter for a store, but it knows about the hierarchy of the tree.

```
var searchStr = Ext.getCmp('searchField').getValue();
var matchingNodes = [];

var tree = Ext.getCmp('infra_tree'); 
// You could get the selected node, or any other node as start node.
// I take the root node as example.
var startNode = tree.getRootNode();

startNode.cascadeBy(function (childNode) {
    if (childNode.get('text') == searchStr)
    {
       matchingNodes.push(childNode);
    }
}, this);
```

You could search any other field in childNode as well obviously. Usually I the nodes I keep in trees have a different model in them. If I have a `teacher` model that is displayed in a tree I have a `teacherTreeModel` that has a `teacher`. So the teacher tree model is not saved in database, only the teacher model. Found that to be easier in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same questions and I just found a fiddle that solves the "search in a tree store" problem. I don't know who wrote it, but it's a gem. It is running here: https - add colon slash slash - fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ra&view/editor
(I tried to include the source code from the fiddle here into the answer, but the Stack Overflow editor doesn't allow me.)