# ExtJs 4.1 TreeGrid Filter through Column Headers

Tags: extjs, extjs4, filtering, extjs4.1, treegrid

I've been searching around and looking into the documentation, but I'm not sure how to activate filtering via the column drop down the way you have it in normal grid panels.

I've tried to implement the `ux.Grid.FilterFeatures` but when I apply it to the tree panel, my panel doesn't render properly (all blue panel). I thought it might have something to do with its deferred layout, but when I do a `treegrid.hide()`/`treegrid.show()`/`treegrid.doLayout()`, it doesn't make a difference.

Has anyone gotten the filter feature working with the treepanel? Or has anyone got any suggestions on how to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tree stores don't have a filtering function, but I had to create one for an earlier project.  [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9642282/1062992) an example.

So, as a suggestion you could create your own filter drop menus using `Ext.grid.header.Container` configs in the tree columns ([as covered here in the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-cfg-columns)) these could be set-up to call some kind of filter function on the treestore like the one I linked to above.

Comment: I tried this, but when node.remove is called the store keeps trying to go back to server. Am i missing something?

Comment: "keeps trying to go back to the server", does that mean the store tries to reload whenever it reaches the call to `node.remove`?

Comment: yes. So it does that for every row that's eligible for filtering.

Comment: reading up, i think this is expected behaviour for the store to try and sync with server when you call remove. setting autosync to false solves this.

Answer (score 2):

I modified the filter example in the [Ext-Js site](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/community/treefilter/viewer.html) to use it in tree grid.

```
Ext.define('TreeGridFilter', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.feature.Feature'
    , alias: 'feature.treeGridFilter'
    , collapseOnClear: true                                             // collapse all nodes when clearing/resetting the filter
    , allowParentFolders: false                                         // allow nodes not designated as 'leaf' (and their child items) to  be matched by the filter
    , treeGrid: null
    , filterPropertyNames: new Array()
    , filterPropertyValues: new Array()
    , filterColumnRenderers: new Array()
    , init: function (tree) {
        var me = this;
        treeGrid = me.tree = tree;
        var view = me.view;
        var headerCt = view.headerCt;

        // Listen for header menu being created
        headerCt.on('menucreate', me.onMenuCreate, me);

        tree.filter = Ext.Function.bind(me.filter, me);
        tree.clearFilter = Ext.Function.bind(me.clearFilter, me);
    }

    ,filter: function (value, property, re, columnRenderer) {
        var me = this
            , tree = me.tree
            , matches = []                                              // array of nodes matching the search criteria
            , root = tree.getRootNode()                                 // root node of the tree
            , property = property || 'text'                             // property is optional - will be set to the 'text' propert of the  treeStore record by default
            , visibleNodes = []                                         // array of nodes matching the search criteria + each parent non-leaf  node up to root
            , viewNode;

        me.updateValueForName(property, value, columnRenderer);
        if (me.filterPropertyNames.length == 0) {                       // if the search field is empty
            me.clearFilter();
            return;
        }

        tree.expandAll();                                               // expand all nodes for the the following iterative routines

        //iterate over all nodes in the tree in order to evalute them against the search criteria
        root.cascadeBy(function (node) {
            var numberOfFiltersMatched = 0;
            for (var index=0; index < me.filterPropertyNames.length; index++)
            {
                var propertyName = me.filterPropertyNames[index];
                var propertyValue = me.filterPropertyValues[index]
                var propertyValueOfNode = node.get(propertyName);
                if(me.filterColumnRenderers[index] != false){
                    var renderingFunction = me.filterColumnRenderers[index];
                    propertyValueOfNode = renderingFunction(propertyValueOfNode);           //Using the renderer function of the column
                }
                var regExpn = new RegExp(propertyValue, "ig")                           // the regExp could be modified to allow for case-sensitive, starts  with, etc.
                if(propertyValueOfNode != null && (propertyValueOfNode+'').match(regExpn)) {
                    numberOfFiltersMatched++;
                }
            }
            if(numberOfFiltersMatched == me.filterPropertyNames.length){
                matches.push(node);                                     // add the node to the matches array
            }
        });

        if (me.allowParentFolders === false) {                          // if me.allowParentFolders is false (default) then remove any non-leaf nodes from the regex match
            Ext.each(matches, function (match) {
                if (match == null || !match.isLeaf()) {
                    Ext.Array.remove(matches, match);
                }
            });
        }

        Ext.each(matches, function (item, i, arr) {                     // loop through all matching leaf nodes
            root.cascadeBy(function (node) {                            // find each parent node containing the node from the matches array
                if (node.contains(item) == true) {
                    visibleNodes.push(node);                            // if it's an ancestor of the evaluated node add it to the visibleNodes  array
                }
            });
            if (me.allowParentFolders === true && !item.isLeaf()) {     // if me.allowParentFolders is true and the item is  a non-leaf item
                item.cascadeBy(function (node) {                        // iterate over its children and set them as visible
                    visibleNodes.push(node);
                });
            }
            visibleNodes.push(item);                                    // also add the evaluated node itself to the visibleNodes array
        });

        root.cascadeBy(function (node) {                                // finally loop to hide/show each node
            viewNode = Ext.fly(tree.getView().getNode(node));           // get the dom element assocaited with each node
            if (viewNode) {                                             // the first one is undefined ? escape it with a conditional
                viewNode.setVisibilityMode(Ext.Element.DISPLAY);        // set the visibility mode of the dom node to display (vs offsets)
                viewNode.setVisible(Ext.Array.contains(visibleNodes, node));
            }
        });
    }

    , clearFilter: function () {
        var me = this
            , tree = this.tree
            , root = tree.getRootNode();

        if (me.collapseOnClear) {
            tree.collapseAll();                                         // collapse the tree nodes
        }
        root.cascadeBy(function (node) {                                // final loop to hide/show each node
            viewNode = Ext.fly(tree.getView().getNode(node));           // get the dom element assocaited with each node
            if (viewNode) {                                             // the first one is undefined ? escape it with a conditional and show  all nodes
                viewNode.show();
            }
        });
    },

    onMenuCreate: function(headerCt, menu) {
        var me = this;
        menu.on('beforeshow', me.onMenuBeforeShow, me);
    },

    onMenuBeforeShow: function(menu) {
        var me = this;
        var currentHeaderFilter = menu.activeHeader.filter;
        if(currentHeaderFilter == null){
            if(me.menuItem == null){
                return;
            }
            me.menuItem.hide();
            me.menuSeparator.hide();
        }else if(me.menuItem != null){
            me.menuItem.show();
            me.menuSeparator.show();
        }
        if(me.menuItem){
            var perviousFilterValue = me.getValueForName(menu.activeHeader.dataIndex);
            if(perviousFilterValue == null || perviousFilterValue == ''){
                me.menuItem.setRawValue('');
            }else{
                me.menuItem.setRawValue(perviousFilterValue);
            }
        }else{
            me.menuSeparator = menu.add('-');

            var filterTextFiels = new Ext.form.TextField({
                itemId: 'filterTextBox',
                cls : 'find-icon',
                listeners: {
                    'change': this.onFilterTextChange
                }
            });
            me.menuItem = menu.add(filterTextFiels);
        }
        me.menuItem.activeDataIndex = menu.activeHeader.dataIndex;
        me.menuItem.activeRenderer = menu.activeHeader.renderer;
        me.menuItem.width = (currentHeaderFilter == null || currentHeaderFilter.width == null) ? 150 : currentHeaderFilter.width;
    },

    onFilterTextChange : function (searchMenuItem, value) {
        treeGrid.filter(value,searchMenuItem.activeDataIndex, null, searchMenuItem.activeRenderer);
    },

    updateValueForName : function(property, value, columnRenderer){
        var propertyIndex = -1;
        for (var index=0; index < this.filterPropertyNames.length; index++)
        {
            if(property == this.filterPropertyNames[index]){
                propertyIndex = index;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(propertyIndex >= 0){
            if(value == null || value == ''){
                this.filterPropertyNames.splice(propertyIndex, 1);
                this.filterPropertyValues.splice(propertyIndex, 1);
                this.filterColumnRenderers.splice(propertyIndex, 1);
            }else{
                this.filterPropertyValues[propertyIndex] = value;
            }
        }else{
            propertyIndex = this.filterPropertyNames.length;
            this.filterPropertyNames[propertyIndex] = property;
            this.filterPropertyValues[propertyIndex] = value;
            this.filterColumnRenderers[propertyIndex] = columnRenderer;
        }
    },

    getValueForName : function(property){
        var propertyIndex = -1;
        for (var index=0; index < this.filterPropertyNames.length; index++)
        {
            if(property == this.filterPropertyNames[index]){
                propertyIndex = index;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(propertyIndex >= 0){
            return this.filterPropertyValues[propertyIndex];
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

This feature can be used in grid as

```
var treeGridFilter = {
    ftype: "treeGridFilter"
};
var treeGrid= Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    id : 'tree-grid-id',
    title: 'View Tree Grid',
    features: [treeGridFilter],
    store: store,
    renderTo: 'grid-div',
    columns: [{
        text: 'Column One',
        dataIndex: 'columnOne',
        filter : {
            width: 150
        }
    },{
        text: 'Column Two',
        dataIndex: 'columnTwo',
        filter : {
            width: 100
        }
    }]
});
```