# ExtJS4.1 Showing Only Excluded Values in Filter

Tags: extjs, extjs4, filtering, extjs4.1

I'm trying to write a filter for a treestore using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627821/filtering-a-treestore-in-ext-js-4) example, and I'm wondering how you tweak/call the filter method so that you can display values that don't match your filter parameter.

I tried to tweak it so that it only called node.remove() when the the filter parameter was wrong. However this doesn't seem to update the store and panel.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To do that I would need to write a custom implementation of Filter.filterfn.

```
Filter({
 filterfn: function(record){
   //Insert Logic
 }
})
```